# Int to Time - Need help understanding the logic behind it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found this code snippet to convert int to time but I would like to understand the logic to the calculations on lines 3-5. I don't understand how this would convert an integer to a time..

```
  SELECT TOP 1
        run_date,run_time,CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date))
        + ((run_time / 10000 * 3600) 
        + ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) 
        + (run_time % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964) AS run_datetime
    FROM
        msdb..sysjobhistory
```

Why do you do all those calculations to get hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds?

I tried to do one by one by I couldn't understand the output then either.

This is all for my learning :)

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: 86,400 = 24*60*60, the number of seconds in a day.  The 86,399.9964 seems like a rather pedantic approximation of a day, taking something into account -- perhaps 365.24 days in a year?

Comment: This is ugly code that relies on the internal representation of `DATETIME` (the whole part is days, the fractional part a fraction of the day) and the fact that T-SQL allows for converting between `DATETIME` and numerical types. There is no compelling reason to not rewrite this with `DATEADD` or some string manipulation with `STUFF`.

Comment: OK, so the string manipulation version isn't necessarily clearer, I'll admit: `run_datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), run_date) + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(STR(run_time, 6), ' ', '0'), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'))`. God only knows why `sysjobhistory` stores dates and times the way it does, it's a textbook example of how not to do it.